# f the function is passed both parameters, it should return the product. If the function is only passed one parameter - it should return a function

Tags: javascript

Write a function called specialMultiply which accepts two parameters. If the function is passed both parameters, it should return the product of the two. If the function is only passed one parameter - it should return a function which can later be passed another parameter to return the product. You will have to use closure and arguments to solve this.
Examples:

```
specialMultiply(3,4); // 12
specialMultiply(3)(4); // 12
specialMultiply(3); // function(){}....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here specialMultiply takes 2 parameter and if both the parameter is int then will get the multiply of 2 params. otherswise it will return the function

```
const specialMultiply = (a, b) => {
   if (parseInt(a) && parseInt(b)) {
      return a*b
   }
   return (b) => {
       return a * b
   }
}

console.log(specialMultiply(3));
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add a few words of explanation!